# How to edit markup/add classes to default WordPress blocks?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a series of custom blocks for WordPress 5.0.0, and really enjoying the Gutenberg experience thus far. However, I'm struggling to find anything online that will allow me to alter the output of default blocks, such as the paragraph block?

For example, the default output of a paragraph block is:

```
<p>Text content</p>
```

But I would like to change it to something like the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="my-class">Text Content</p>
</div>
```

If I can't achieve the above, then I will need to replace the default blocks with custom ones, which seems crazy given the blocks they have available.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you've found online. This seems like a good resource for what you're looking to do: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-gutenberg-block-api-extending-blocks--cms-31320

Comment: Thanks @danwebb, looks like a useful resource

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **editor.BlockEdit** [hook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) to modify the block’s edit component.

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;

const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>
                        My custom control
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, are you able to let me know where this kind of markup should go? Typically I'm used to using functions.php however blocks seem to use a new language/syntax? Thanks.

Comment: I believe much if not all customization and additions for Gutenberg Blocks happens in Javascript in the admin editor pages. See https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg uses the JS library React.js for front-end rendering now meaning that in many cases PHP won't do the trick. Both front- and back-end are becoming detached from each-other as WordPress becomes decoupled (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/10/headless-wordpress-decoupled/).

If you're using ACF to create Gutenberg blocks then you can still have control using PHP and HTML, other than that it's down to JS.